# Error failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: failed to solve with frontend docker

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, fetch, fly

I am trying to deploy my website from heroku to fly.io

and when I did fly deploy I got this error

```
Error failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = quay.io/evl.ms/fullstaq-ruby:2.6.1-jemalloc-slim: not found
```

fly.toml file

```
# fly.toml file generated for ancient-tree-3915 on 2022-09-22T15:00:52-07:00

app = "ancient-tree-3915"
kill_signal = "SIGINT"
kill_timeout = 5
processes = []

[build]
  [build.args]
    BUILD_COMMAND = "bin/rails fly:build"
    SERVER_COMMAND = "bin/rails fly:server"

[deploy]
  release_command = "bin/rails fly:release"

[env]
  PORT = "8080"

[experimental]
  allowed_public_ports = []
  auto_rollback = true

[[services]]
  http_checks = []
  internal_port = 8080
  processes = ["app"]
  protocol = "tcp"
  script_checks = []
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 25
    soft_limit = 20
    type = "connections"

  [[services.ports]]
    force_https = true
    handlers = ["http"]
    port = 80

  [[services.ports]]
    handlers = ["tls", "http"]
    port = 443

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    grace_period = "1s"
    interval = "15s"
    restart_limit = 0
    timeout = "2s"

[[statics]]
  guest_path = "/app/public"
  url_prefix = "/"
```

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you add the `fly.toml` file and explain the steps you undertake (which command do you use, etc..)?

Answer (score 0):

This `quay.io/evl.ms/fullstaq-ruby:2.6.1-jemalloc-slim` image (probably used in you Dockerfile's `FROM` clause) doesn't really exist. Check it yourself [here](https://quay.io/repository/evl.ms/fullstaq-ruby?tab=tags):

[image]

So, the lowest available 2.6.x tag on quay.io is `2.6.3-jemalloc-stretch-slim`. Probably, they just purged old, unsupported versions.

Try to upgrade to a newer version.